# Applications that leverage Microsoft AJAX.NET (Atlas) can be vulnerable to JavaScript hijacking,

Tags: asp.net

I  am getting a finding in my scan indicating that my code is vulnerable to JavaScript hijacking. My code dynamically generate all of the page content, including the Ajax ScriptManager. Because the content is not in the webpage as static markup it is my opinion that this is a false finding. Can someone review my code and either confirm or deny my belief and if I am incorrect recommend a proper implementation.

```
    private void CreateControls(ControlCollection cc)
    {
        if (RadScriptManager.GetCurrent(_contextPage) == null)
        {
            RadScriptManager rsm = new RadScriptManager();
            rsm.ID = "scriptManager";
            cc.Add(rsm);
        }
```

Comment: I assume this is coming from Fortify? The fact that your content is all loaded via JavaScript actually would make it more vulnerable, not less (assuming you don't mean it's generated "dynamically" with back-end code). See this post for more info: http://haacked.com/archive/2009/06/25/json-hijacking.aspx/ However, see this article discussing how ASP.NET AJAX mitigates this type of attack: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/json-hijacking-and-how-asp-net-ajax-1-0-mitigates-these-attacks Note that this only affects you if your JavaScript uses GET, not POST, to fetch the data.